# Inline create/edit functionality like in Django's admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

I want to implement an inline create/edit functionality like in Django's admin site. (see picture below)
[image]

This is what I got so far:
For dynamically adding and removing the form, I use django-dynamic-formset jquery plugin.

[image]

Any suggestions or ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any further with this? This is a related question with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405018/django-creating-an-inline-formset-similar-to-the-admin-interface